# Graphing logarithmic functions from exponential functions

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

[! textbook explanation on deriving the graph of a logarithmic function[][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nocFe.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nocFe.jpg)

In this write up the author interchanged the axes and then reflected the graph. But this is supposed to be the same thing, the author interchanged the axes, but the graph didn't change in fig.3.3. I know for a fact that the graph of a logarithmic function the same as reflecting the graph of an exponential function about the line y=x. Is this explanation wrong?

Comment: Swapping the axes is the same as reflecting about the line $y=x$ and in fig 3.3 you can see that they have in fact swapped each axis so the graph did change.

Comment: Look at the picture more carefully -- note that the labels "$x$" and "$y$" on the axes have been swapped